# response gnocchi measures empty

Tags: openstack, ceilometer

i want to use gnocchi Stein version but i have problem with it, because all measures is empty and i don't know how to solve it. in the blew i show the configuration and command lists:

in the gnocchi.conf:

```
 [storage] coordination_url = redis://controller:6379
 file_basepath = /var/lib/gnocchi
 driver = file
```

in the ceilometer/pipeline.yaml :

```
 publishers: - gnocchi://?filter_project=service&archive_policy=high
```

(i so test with medium and low)

in the compute i only ceilometer-agent-compute install

> gnocchi metric list

```
+--------------------------------------+---------------------+----------------------------+---------+--------------------------------------+
| id                                   | archive_policy/name | name                       | unit    | resource_id                          |
+--------------------------------------+---------------------+----------------------------+---------+--------------------------------------+
| 1e785d3d-3f04-47c1-90b7-42ffbffc691d | ceilometer-low-rate | network.outgoing.packets   | packet  | 9284f4b1-1706-56d1-9727-4a1a534b9351 |
| 44789dfd-bd40-4a1e-bb69-acfc7da0d07f | ceilometer-low-rate | disk.device.read.bytes     | B       | 789282b6-cf18-5cea-9726-90f49645e964 |
| 470d813e-fdcf-42ef-bda7-e8176702333f | ceilometer-low-rate | cpu                        | ns      | 5831590b-f777-43cf-b371-f0e972e302e0 |
| 52687228-77f3-4110-b4ce-65d2265251ff | ceilometer-low      | disk.ephemeral.size        | GB      | 5831590b-f777-43cf-b371-f0e972e302e0 |
| 58fe4bd5-d9db-470a-9611-5bd9f0d32ad2 | ceilometer-low      | memory                     | MB      | 5831590b-f777-43cf-b371-f0e972e302e0 |
| 6453d474-1f73-421f-bbc3-2ad9f1f6a75f | ceilometer-low-rate | disk.device.write.requests | request | 789282b6-cf18-5cea-9726-90f49645e964 |
| 8717da56-a006-4f29-96e0-b8051eaa9519 | ceilometer-low-rate | network.incoming.packets   | packet  | 9284f4b1-1706-56d1-9727-4a1a534b9351 |
| 9371c616-13b0-419c-9d42-71aa1d56e97d | ceilometer-low-rate | disk.device.write.bytes    | B       | 789282b6-cf18-5cea-9726-90f49645e964 |
| c14b4768-73d9-40c1-b599-58bb68ab3e3f | ceilometer-low      | vcpus                      | vcpu    | 5831590b-f777-43cf-b371-f0e972e302e0 |
| ca1e92d5-35f3-423f-a6eb-b3cda281d32d | ceilometer-low-rate | network.incoming.bytes     | B       | 9284f4b1-1706-56d1-9727-4a1a534b9351 |
| db1d313e-40d5-47f6-8403-6587f6e9ecb1 | ceilometer-low      | memory.usage               | MB      | 5831590b-f777-43cf-b371-f0e972e302e0 |
| deeb45da-0c6b-47d7-90b2-7d6247976323 | ceilometer-low      | disk.root.size             | GB      | 5831590b-f777-43cf-b371-f0e972e302e0 |
| df5b15c9-bbc4-42c7-a3f7-99b8f5568803 | ceilometer-low-rate | disk.device.read.requests  | request | 789282b6-cf18-5cea-9726-90f49645e964 |
| e2edde4e-74cf-4948-b1e1-38e86157dc3e | ceilometer-low-rate | network.outgoing.bytes     | B       | 9284f4b1-1706-56d1-9727-4a1a534b9351 |
+--------------------------------------+---------------------+----------------------------+---------+--------------------------------------+
```

> gnocchi metric show c14b4768-73d9-40c1-b599-58bb68ab3e3f

```
+--------------------------------+-------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Field                          | Value                                                             |
+--------------------------------+-------------------------------------------------------------------+
| archive_policy/name            | ceilometer-low                                                    |
| creator                        | bc4221d78ed84fa4aaf7500aba3eee8f:841727edc3014652bf4619e7c05d4d2f |
| id                             | c14b4768-73d9-40c1-b599-58bb68ab3e3f                              |
| name                           | vcpus                                                             |
| resource/created_by_project_id | 841727edc3014652bf4619e7c05d4d2f                                  |
| resource/created_by_user_id    | bc4221d78ed84fa4aaf7500aba3eee8f                                  |
| resource/creator               | bc4221d78ed84fa4aaf7500aba3eee8f:841727edc3014652bf4619e7c05d4d2f |
| resource/ended_at              | None                                                              |
| resource/id                    | 5831590b-f777-43cf-b371-f0e972e302e0                              |
| resource/original_resource_id  | 5831590b-f777-43cf-b371-f0e972e302e0                              |
| resource/project_id            | 325ea229bd7241ce8dd488b6716bdf5c                                  |
| resource/revision_end          | None                                                              |
| resource/revision_start        | 2019-11-16T14:44:15.740027+00:00                                  |
| resource/started_at            | 2019-11-16T14:43:10.541605+00:00                                  |
| resource/type                  | instance                                                          |
| resource/user_id               | 8d0f277add03403b94c2b568449de598                                  |
| unit                           | vcpu                                                              |
+--------------------------------+-------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

> gnocchi measures show e2edde4e-74cf-4948-b1e1-38e86157dc3e

## empty response

while add same error:

> gnocchi measures add -r 5831590b-f777-43cf-b371-f0e972e302e0 -m 2019-01-28T08:00:39@300 cpu

500 Internal Server Error  Internal Server Error

The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.

Please contact the server administrator at [no address given] to inform them of the time this error occurred, and the actions you performed just before this error.

More information about this error may be available in the server error log.

Apache/2.4.29 (Ubuntu) Server at controller Port 8041
 (HTTP 500)